# Is it possible to split partition on Bitlocker encrypted drive?

Tags: partitioning, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I'm currently using Bitlocker encrypted external hard drive. It's single partition and the entire disk is encrypted.

I'd like to split the single partition into two partitions while enabling Bitlocker encryption. Can it be done without turning encryption off?

Comment: I'm Sure it is but back up all data before attempting, there is high risk involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a Bitlocker partition cannot be shrunk.

You can see this in Disk Management : Right-click the partition and you will see that
the "Shrink Volume..." option is gray and disabled.

There is no other option than turning encryption off (waiting as required),
then shrinking the partition and creating the second partition in the new
unallocated space.
Do NOT try to shrink the partition using any third-party product.

Be sure to backup first your entire disk from inside Windows, in addition to the
backup of your data.
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/?adb)
is a good backup utility that also has a boot CD/USB for emergencies.

Comment: That's funny. My system thinks it can shrink a BitLocker volume. (I don't actually need to right now.)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Disk Management in Windows 11.
First I shrink the C:\ drive (ssd) and D:\ drive (hdd) of PC, both with BitLocker enabled; it took 10 seconds and created an unallocated memory which I then partitioned.

Other third-party software warned that I had to first disable BitLocker and then shrink, but with Disk Management did it without problem with BitLocker enabled.

Note: on disk D:\ I had to do defragmentation first, otherwise Disk Management couldn't shrink too much.